# Elisp: how to avoid "functions are not known to be defined" when byte-compiling?

Tags: emacs, elisp

My package, `lispy`, uses a function from `ace-jump-mode`.
I'm still thinking if I should use `;; Package-Requires:` cookie
or `featurep` for it, but the main issue is that I want a clean byte-compile
with `emacs -q`.

I thought that this should eliminate the byte-compilation warning:

```
(declare-function ace-jump-char-mode "ext:ace-jump-mode")
```

But it's not the case. Any thoughts on this?

Exactly, the warning is "the following functions are not known to be defined: ace-jump-char-mode, helm".

Comment: Couldn't you just use `featurep` + `require`? Or `fboundp` for that particular function and then declare it or require the package?

Comment: You mean `(and (featurep 'ace-jump-mode) (require 'ace-jump-mode))`?
`emacs -q` will not see it because `featurep` will return `nil`.

Comment: Mmm... I see. In theory, `declare-function` does whan you want, but you have to specify the `.el` file that actually implements that defines that function. Is `"ext:ace-jump-mode"` exactly the file?

Comment: Yes, it is. But it's not in the load-path since `-q`.

Comment: The docs say that the compiler will ignore the function. Sorry, out of ideas here. You do that before using the function, right? Perhaps you could put around an `eval-when-compile` and see if this works.

Comment: I was expecting some better mechanism, i.e. I say to the compiler: "I know that this function is not declared
here, but elsewhere. Don't bug me about this one, but still show warnings for other functions.".
Something akin to declaration in C++: compiler doesn't care to find the function, it's linker's job.

Comment: But this is exactly what `declare-function` is for, at least that's what is said in the docs...

Comment: What is the exact error message? Please complete your question.

Comment: Are you sure that you put `declare-function` BEFORE the first usage of the functions? If it is a lot code could you try to put the `declare-function` at the very beginning? Could you re-check the spelling in the first argument in the `declare-function` forms?

Comment: The spelling will not be the problem as the example you gave is right. There only remains the requirement that `declare-function` must come before the usage of the function.

Comment: Thanks, @Tobias. Putting it at the top solved it. I don't think it was in the doc that I should put it at the top. Anyway, issue resolved.

Comment: Should update with a link to the Emacs docs on [Compiler Errors](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Compiler-Errors.html#Compiler-Errors).

Answer (score 3):

If that function is likely to be used in most cases where lispy is used, then you shoud just use something like `(require 'ext:ace-jump-mode)`.

Comment: But why doesn't `declare-function` let me ignore the warning?
Also, I'd like to implement a discover-able feature behavior, e.g. if the user
has `ace-jump-mode` installed, use that, otherwise - use something else.
For instance, regarding completion, a user may prefer `helm` or `icicles` but not both.
So why should I `require` both of them if my package allows to use either one or the other?

Comment: I don't know why declare-function doesn't work for you, since you didn't even show the exact warning you got.  As for the other question, I recommend you use `(fboundp 'ace-jump-char-mode)`.

Comment: The warning is "the following functions are not known to be defined: ace-jump-char-mode, helm".
And `fboundp` is an approach that I'm already using, but it doesn't help with byte-compile warnings.

Comment: The point is that these functions should not be defined, since I'm testing with `emacs -q`, but I thought that there should be no warning because I used `declare-function`

Comment: The byte compiler does not emit warnings for function calls guarded by `fboundp`, e.g. `(when (fboundp 'foo) (foo))` will not emit a warning, when `foo` is not defined.